# structural type extending another structural type

Tags: scala, types, structural-typing, compound-type

Why the following is not allowed? (2.12):

```scala
type Foo <: {def foo(): Unit}
type Bar <: {def bar(): Unit} with Foo
```

Looks natural to me, `Bar` should have both `foo()` and `bar()`.

Comment: Dotty appears to allow it.

Comment: By the way, `<:` is not extending (inheriatance) but subtyping. https://www.cmi.ac.in/~madhavan/courses/pl2009/lecturenotes/lecture-notes/node28.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`type Foo <: {def foo(): Unit}` is `type Foo <: AnyRef{def foo(): Unit}`.

So while `type Bar <: {def bar(): Unit} with Foo` is not parsable, with `AnyRef` and different order it works

```
type Foo <: {def foo(): Unit}
type Bar <: Foo with AnyRef{def bar(): Unit}

val b: Bar = ???
b.foo()
b.bar()
```

Also with brackets (and direct order) it works

```
type Foo <: {def foo(): Unit}
type Bar <: ({def bar(): Unit}) with Foo 

val b: Bar = ???
b.foo()
b.bar()
```

---

Actually `type Bar <: {def bar(): Unit} with Foo` is against the spec while `type Bar <: ({def bar(): Unit}) with Foo` satisfies the spec because `{def bar(): Unit}` is not a `SimpleType` but `({def bar(): Unit})` is a `SimpleType`.

```
CompoundType    ::=  AnnotType {‘with’ AnnotType} [Refinement]
                  |  Refinement

AnnotType       ::=  SimpleType {Annotation}

SimpleType      ::= ............
                  |  ‘(’ Types ‘)’

Types           ::=  Type {‘,’ Type}

Type            ::=  ...........
                  |  CompoundType
                  |  ...........
```

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#compound-types

Answer (score 9):

Seems to work with parenthesis

```
scala> type Foo <: {def foo(): Unit}
     | type Bar <: ({def bar(): Unit}) with Foo
type Foo
type Bar
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not allowed by the spec, which calls the `{ ...}` part a refinement which may both have a with clause. The other way around it's fine though.

That's somewhat tautological of course as it doesn't say why it's not allowed by the spec. It appears there is no deep understanding here, just that that's not a way you're allowed to write a type. You should be able to express the same intent in another way.

Comment: Why do you think it's not allowed by the spec? https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#compound-types `CompoundType ::= AnnotType {‘with’ AnnotType} [Refinement] | Refinement`. Here `{def bar(): Unit}` and `Foo` are `AnnotType`s, `Refinement` is empty.

Comment: @DmytroMitin `AnnotType` is `SimpleType {Annotation}` but `{def bar(): Unit}` is not a `SimpleType`

Comment: Right, `{def bar(): Unit}` is not a `SimpleType` but `({def bar(): Unit})` is a `SimpleType`.

Comment: is it though @DmytroMitin? The compiler accepts it as if it is, but I can't figure out how that works from the spec

Comment: Yes. `SimpleType ::= SimpleType TypeArgs | SimpleType ‘#’ id | StableId | Path ‘.’ ‘type’ | Literal | ‘(’ Types ‘)’`. Important is the last part, if you surround `Types` with brackets then you get a `SimpleType`. `Types ::= Type {‘,’ Type}`, so one `Type` is also `Types`. `{def bar(): Unit}` is a `Type` (actually a `CompoundType` consisting of single `Refinement`), so `({def bar(): Unit})` is a `SimpleType`.

Comment: Ah, yes, there it is.